# Wrong Epoch time while sync with NTP server

Tags: wireshark, ntp

I have two clients which are synchronized with the NTP server. I am trying to measure the latency of packet from client1 to client2. But the Epoch time still does not make sense because the packet sending time is sometime is greater than the packet receiving time in Wireshark. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `ntpq -4 -u -c peer <host>` should give you the information you need. The `ntpq` is part of `ntpsec` although it may also work with the standard `ntpd` tools.

```
eth6:~ # ntpq -4 -u -c pee localhost
     remote                                   refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset   jitter
=======================================================================================================
*ntphost                                     .PPS.       1 u    4   32  377 1.6921ms -1.641ms 2.9671ms
eth6:~ # ntpq -4 -u -c pee ntphost
     remote                                   refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset   jitter
=======================================================================================================
oPPS(0)                                      .PPS.       0 l    1    8  377      0ns    793ns    640ns
+SHM(0)                                      .SHM.       0 l   14   16  377      0ns   -633ns    870ns
```

Comment: I have 
ntp server: 172.22.x.x
ntp client1
ntp client2
I want to to measure time between client1 and client 2
I did the above mentioned command you told but -u is not an option?

Comment: The `-u` is only then available with `ntpsec` and you may be better running with it rather that the original `ntpd`. The `-u` switch will give nanosecond results. I've updated the answer with an example...

Comment: Hi @Bib , So the offset in your answer is the time difference between the NTP client and NTP server?
If yes, do the client changes its clock time with this offset?

Comment: That would be over simplistic. They will use delay, offset & jitter along with a lot of mathematics to sync the clocks.

Comment: Hi Bob, the next question following to it is 
https://superuser.com/questions/1753753/measuring-epoch-time-in-wireshark-of-ntp-client
could you answer me that also. Thank you